# Storing floating point numbers in android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, floating-point

I'm trying to store dollar amounts in the sqlite database provided by android but it doesn't seem to work properly.  This error only occurs when I try to remove a transaction that aren't whole dollar amounts. i.e. 409.00 will work but 410.44 won't.

If I store a value such as 410.44 and then query the database for that amount I don't get a match. I've tried to use this field as the REAL datatype and the TEXT datatype but neither works.  In the following example the getTransAmount() method returns a float.  This is the version i ran when I had the db datatype as REAL.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
cv.put(transAmount, t.getTransAmount());

db.insert(tableName, null, cv);
x = db.delete(tableName, transAmount + " = " + t.getTransAmount(), null);
```

Comment: I store mine as text and parse them after i get them from the DB, but I don't use many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't use floating-point to store currency amounts.** Floating-point is inaccurate; as you have found out, floating-point comparisons are especially tricky to deal with.

I normally store currency amounts in the database as integers, e.g. `410.44` would be stored as `41044`, and `409.00` as `40900`.

When you need to convert to the `410.44` format for display, you can use the `BigDecimal` class, passing it the scale to use (2 in this case) which is the number of digits to shift the decimal point by.

Example:

```
int        storedAmount = 41044;
BigDecimal scaledAmount = new BigDecimal(storedAmount);
scaledAmount.setScale(2);  // now contains 410.44
```

Comment: no, `scaledAmount` still will contain 41044. you need to divide it by 100. `setScale()` is not enough.

Comment: if you "divide it by 100" you get floating point arithmetic, which is what currency types should avoid at all costs